# Contentful API with next.js undefined error

Tags: next.js, contentful

I'm getting an undefined error when making a graphql request to contentful using next.js framework. I created a page for "news" where I receive all posts and that works perfectly. But when I make **dynamic pages** on nextjs I am getting an undefined response from contentful. See what I mean below.

// news/[slug].tsx

```
import { Box, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React from "react";
import { fetchContent } from "../../utils/contentful";

const NewsArticlePage = ({ post }) => {
  console.log("post", post.slug);
  return (
    <Box>
      <Text>{post.title}</Text>
      <Text>{post.slug}</Text>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default NewsArticlePage; 


export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  // Fetch necessary data for the blog post using params.id

  console.log("context params slug", context.params.slug);

  const response = await fetchContent(`
         query getBlogPost($slug: String) {
            blogPostCollection(where: {slug: ${context.params.slug}}) {
                items {
                title
                slug
                }
            }
        }
    `);

  console.log("response", response);

  const post = response.blogPostCollection.items.pop();

  if (!post) {
    return { props: {} };
  }

  // Return the post as props
  return {
    props: {
      post,
    },
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Return a list of possible value for id

const response = await fetchContent(`
         {
    blogPostCollection {
      items {
        contentfulMetadata {
         tags {
          id
          name
        } 
        }
        title
        slug
        description
        body
        heroImage {
          title
          description
          contentType
          fileName
          size
          url
          width
          height
        }
        author {
          name
          title
          company
          shortBio
          email
          phone
          facebook
          twitter
          github
        }
        publishDate
        tags
      }
    }
  }


                `);


    console.log('response' ,response);

  const paths = response.blogPostCollection.items.map((post) => ({
    params: {
      slug: post.slug,
    },
  }));

//   console.log(paths);

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

fetchContent is a hook I'm using which just fetches the content by passing in the query. Here is the hook:

```
// utils/contentful
const space = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID;
const accessToken = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN;

export async function fetchContent(query) {
  // add a try / catch loop for nicer error handling
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://graphql.contentful.com/content/v1/spaces/${space}`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
        // throw our query (a string) into the body directly
        body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
      }
    );
    const { data } = await res.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    // add a descriptive error message first,
    // so we know which GraphQL query caused the issue
    console.error(
      `There was a problem retrieving entries with the query ${query}`
    );
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Like I said, the news page, which fetches the same query (blogPostCollection) gets all of the posts. But the dynamically created posts get stuck with undefined response. Appreciate any help. Thanks

I forgot to mention that in graphiql, the query is working perfectly. There is nothing wrong with the query for single posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `getStaticPaths` to statically generate all of the different static pages based on the slugs.

See the Next.js documentation here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation

Here's a code example to add to your [slug].js page:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const blogPostSlugs = // fetch all blog post slugs via GraphQL

  // For example
  //
  // const query = `{
  //   blogPostCollection {
  //     items {
  //       slug
  //      }
  //    }
  //  }`;

  const paths = blogPostSlugs.map((slug) => {
    return { params: { slug } };
  });

  return {
    paths,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // Do whatever you need to fetch your post
  const post = // fetch your post via slug as you do above using params.slug

  return {
    props: {
      post,
    },
  };
}
```

For a full code example, see this file on GitHub: https://github.com/whitep4nth3r/nextjs-contentful-blog-starter/blob/d80dc1e44a827bc3e6e30ca8c699a4b60f626040/pages/blog/%5Bslug%5D.js#L26

Comment: I used getStaticPaths. I was getting a serialize error from the fetchContent function. I found the github example helpful though. Thank you.